# The cardinality of the set of strict local maxima on any continuous real-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(x):\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. How to prove that $f$ can have at most countably many strict local maxima?

I've been thinking about choosing a rational point for each local maxima in $(x_0 -\delta;x_0 + \delta)$ where $f(x_0) > f(x)$ for any $x \in (x_0 -\delta;x_0 + \delta)$. But how to do that so for different $x_1$ and $x_2$ stand different
 points?

Comment: @postmortes, I don't get there last part: The set of strict local maxima is a countable union of such sets, for example taking $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ as n ranges over the positive integers.

Comment: why we can say so?

Comment: since ${\mathbb N}$ is countable, $1/n$ for $n \in {\mathbb N}$ is also countable: the map $f: n \rightarrow 1/n$ is one-to-one so preserves the countability.  In fact, any one-to-one transformation for your $\delta$ will preserve countability